# How can i fix the error that error said has dependancy

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

can any help me regarding this issue? I have already install all libaries but the code is not working. In the figure shows the error. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.